# HTML | Subir y mostrar Lista de reproduccion aleatoria

Tags: javascript, html, lista, audio

quisiera saber si hay alguna libreria ya sea de Javascript con html o alguno, que me de la opcion de subir una lista de produccion y darle algun nombre, y luego poder mostrar la lista como una playlist y que haya una opcion de reproducirla aleatoriamente.

Estoy haciendo una pagina para subir algunas playlist y que se pueda mostrar en la pagina y almacenar las musicas en una carpeta o en alguna base datos(Pero creo que a la larga terminara pesando bastante).

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es una API, spotify te ofrece una(aunque existen muchas mas):

https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/

Puedes crear listas de reproduccion, buscar musicas por artistas, por albumes, generos, etc. Noto que eres novato, y te animo a que no te des por vencido. Suerte!

Comment: Buen aporte no sabía que había eso, ¿sabes que limitaciones hay?

Comment: La principal limitación que encontré cuando lo utilicé, es el uso de tokens. Debido a que si lo utilizas en tu página web, este debe ser renovado para poder seguir consumiendo datos del API cada hora. Lo ideal es que automatices este proceso de generación de token, pero debes saber algo de BACKEND . Spotify tambien te ofrece la opción de evitar el uso de tokens pero los usuarios de tu sitio web deberán loguearse con su cuenta Spotify para usar el servicio sin problemas. Pero existen muchas otras opciones como:
https://rapidapi.com/musixmatch.com/api/musiXmatch